# How do I call a method that takes in no parameter but returns a few values in another python file?

Tags: python, function, methods, method-call

I would like to make use of this read_config() method to be called in another python file. This method takes in no parameter but returns the root_dir, ednotes_name and ednotes_output as shown below.

The problem is that I am not sure how to make use and call this method in another python file. Please help by looking at my codes, thanks!! :((

```
def read_config():
    #read configuration
    csf_config_txt = open("..\CFS_Config.txt", "r")

    file_list = []
    root_dir = ""
    ednotes_name = ""
    ednotes_output = ""

    for line in csf_config_txt:
        file_list.append(line)

    if "Folder Path = " in file_list[0]:
        root_dir = str(file_list[0])
        root_dir = root_dir.replace("Folder Path = ", "")
        root_dir = root_dir.replace("\n", "")

    if "ED Notes name = " in file_list[1]:
        ednotes_name = str(file_list[1])
        ednotes_name =  ednotes_name.replace("ED Notes name = ", "")
        ednotes_name =  ednotes_name.replace("\n", "")

    if "ED Notes output = " in file_list[2]:
        ednotes_output = str(file_list[2])
        ednotes_output = ednotes_output.replace("ED Notes output = ", "")
        ednotes_output = ednotes_output.replace("\n", "")

    return root_dir, ednotes_name, ednotes_output
```

Answer (score 1):

If this function is in `module.py`, a file at your project root, then to call `read_config()` from another Python module at the project root you can do something like this:

```
import module
root_dir, ednotes_name, ednotes_output = module.read_config()
```